# Catch data from url like someplace.com/mydata i want catch mydata

Tags: php

say my URL is:

```
someplace.com/mydata
```

How can I get the `mydata` from the URL ?

Example, If I visit [facebook.com/alshahrior](http://facebook.com/alshahrior) it's show my [fb](http://facebook.com) profile. How can I do that using PHP ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: What do you mean by "get the mydata from the URL"?

Comment: @Antoni I mean if someome visit mysite.com/Sagor its would be mysite.com/profile.php?id=Sagor . Like facebook example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
$url = "http://someplace.com/mydata";

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```